# android - set text for spinner in <include />

Tags: android, spinner

I would like to set text for the spinners in the layout reused. However, only the first spinner is set. How to set text for all spinners with same id?

Also, I would like to ask how add another skillfield.xml to fragment_skill.xml when clicking the imageview?

Thank you.

fragment_skill.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/skillInfo" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/OCC"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/occ"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/occSkill"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/occPt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/occ"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/oocSkill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/occ"
        layout="@layout/skillfield" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addOccSkill"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/oocSkill"
        android:contentDescription="@string/delSkill"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ORI"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/OCC" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ori"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/oriSkill"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oriPt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ori"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/oriSkill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ori"
        layout="@layout/skillfield" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addOriSkill"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/oriSkill"
        android:contentDescription="@string/delSkill"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

skillfield.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/addSkillField" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/selectSkill"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/skillPt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" 
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/addSkill"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:contentDescription="@string/delSkill"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In MainActivity.class

```
skill = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectSkill);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> skillAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.skills, R.layout.spinner);
skillAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_down);
skill.setAdapter(skillAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to setup `Spinner` with the same ID

It is true that if you do this:
`skill = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectSkill);`

You will be only able to get the first `Spinner`. I don't think you can add new `Spinner` dynamically by using `<include>`.

Here's the main idea of how to achieve what you need:

In `fragment_skill.xml`, you need to add an empty container view. This container should be inserted in the place you want to add your `Spinner` every time the button is clicked. This container will hold your `Spinner`s that are added.

Let's say you want to insert here:

```
<RelativeLayout...>
    <TextView.../>
    <TextView.../>
    <!-- here is where you want to insert your Spinner -->
    <ImageView.../>
</RelativeLayout...>
```

So you add a `LinearLayout` at that spot, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout...>
    <TextView.../>
    <TextView.../>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="vertical
        ... />
    <ImageView.../>
</RelativeLayout...>
```

You can add any other type of layout, depending what you need, it doesn't have to be `LinearLayout`. After that, you grab that `LinearLayout` from your activity/fragment like this:

```
 LinearLayout mContainer; // make this instance variable
 mContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
```

Also grab the button so that you can set up a listener, let's assume it's called `Button mButton`:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addNewSpinner();
    });
```

So when the button is clicked, you will call `addNewSpinner()`. Now, make a method called `addNewSpinner()`. Inside, the method, we will be inflating `skillfield.xml`. The method should look something like this:

```
public void addNewSpinner(){
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.skillfield, null);
    Spinner skill = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.selectSkill);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> skillAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.skills, R.layout.spinner);
    skillAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_down);
    skill.setAdapter(skillAdapter);
    mContainer.addView(skill);
}
```

If you are not sure what `inflate` means, here is the explanation:

> Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects.

Hope it helps!